# Add a new column to a dataframe with the percentage of every value of this dataframe

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below and I would like to add a new column with the percentage of every value of this dataframe. Something like:

```
name <- c("asdad","dssdd")
number <- c(5,5)
df <- data.frame(name,number)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  percentage<-df[i,1]/sum(df$number)
}

new <- cbind(df, percentage)
```

but I get NAs instead of percentages.

Comment: Firstly, you are dividing a `character` with `number` and obviously you should expect `NA`. Secondly, you are appending the `percentage` vector, you are just modifying it with the current value.

Comment: You don't need to use `for` loop for that, if you still insist on using it here is the code, `percentage <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  percentage[i]<-df[i,1]/sum(df$number)
  
}`

Comment: Better way would be `df %>% mutate(Percentage = number/sum(number))`

Comment: I like the mutate solution

Comment: feel free to accept the answer

Comment: Do you want the answer in base R, dplyr, data.table, all of these or don't-care?

Comment: Im covered with the answers below thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, below is the solution.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Percentage = number/sum(number))

Output:
   name number Percentage
1 asdad      5       0.25
2 dssdd      5       0.25
3  assa     10       0.50
```

Comment: Both `%>%` and `mutate` are added by dplyr and will not work in base R. You should probably add that information to your solution.

Comment: @SweepingsDemon, My bad!! smci beat me to it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you looping? Furthermore, why are you changing a single variable and then trying to bind it like a vector?

A much easier way to do this is to just add a column, i.e. `df$percentage <- df$number/sum(df$number)*100`

Comment: I will eventually use it in a dynamic dataframe inside a shiny app which will not have stable number of rows

Comment: @firmo23 you don't need to know the number of rows to apply a function or append a column.